# Sudden web form positioning problems on VS 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms, designer

I have an asp.net 2.0 web site project (not web application) in VS 2010 that was working all along. I was trying to change the html source of a web form when all of a sudden, the positioning is messed up on all web forms in the designer and also in the development server. All the buttons are now big in height and messed up in position. This happens for all web forms whether or not using a master form.

All other web site projects work just fine, implying that VS 2010 is fine and not corrupted.

I have tried the following:

1. Closed and reopened the project.
2. Rebooted.
3. Verified that asp.net 2.0 is the target.
4. Deleted the web site solution from C:\Users folder and reopened,
   recreated keeping asp.net 2.0.

Both the files for all web forms are not changed when compared with earlier backup. In fact, I have them deployed where they work just fine.

Another clue is that even if I run the web site independently in Utildev Cassini, it shows the same problem.

Any ideas what can be wrong? Is there something other than the solution file where VS 2010 saves some settings for web site projects?

Comment: Is there a CSS file that's missing or the link to it is broken?

Comment: Yes, you guessed correctly! Finally found it in firebug. One of my css files got disturbed and a height was introduced in a common place. Not sure how that happened. I was on the wrong track by suspecting visual studio designer.